# Check if file matching regex, glob, or wildcard pattern exists?

Tags: ruby

I'm aware of `File.exists?`, but that appears to operate with strings or IO objects. What I need is the ability to use a regex, glob, or wildcard.

For example, I want to say `File.exists?("/pictures/tank_man.*")`, to see if an image named tank_man exists, whether it's a jpg, tif, png, whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Dir["/pictures/tank_man.*"]`
It will return existing paths

Comment: Thanks, this is fantastic. Had no idea Dir could do that.